# nodejs Stack Traces in Output Window (Netbeans) Containing a Clickable Link to the Error Line

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans

I'm runnning nodejs in Netbeans 8.2. When an exception is thrown I'm getting the error on the Console Output window. The filepath:linenumber of the error is written in the Output.
When debugging some browser side script, I can click on the line in the console output window and the editor opens directly the error line. But this is not working in the nodejs Output.

How can I enable this feature for the nodejs Output?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is not yet implemented. Please file a bug for it, with steps to reproduce here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS

This feature is more or less complete for Java and other type of languages. But not that consistent, unfortunately.